# Moving a NSString to a UIView from a different class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, xcode4

I currently have two classes. Class A has my UIView attached to it. My second Class, Class B has some other functions that works in the background. I have one function that ends up with a string. Is there a easy way to move that string from Class B to Class A that has the UIView.

Comment: What is the relationship between Class A and Class B?  Depending on the nature of the relationship, there are several options (design patterns, really)  NSNotificationCenter, delegate pattern, handler blocks.  The answer is contingent on the application design.

Comment: You can do this by defining a delegate method in B and implementing it at A. Then you can call this method at B when it is ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure -- just make sure that the instance of B has a reference to the instance of A that you want to pass the string to.

***Rule:** Any time you want one object, say `foo`, to be able to communicate directly with another object, `bar`, then `foo` needs a pointer to `bar`.*

Communication between objects isn't always direct -- some other object (or objects) may act as intermediaries. That doesn't change the rule above; indirect communication is just a sequence of direct communications. If `foo` uses a notification to communicate with `bar`, `foo` needs a pointer to the notification center, and the notification center needs a pointer to `bar`.