# Sharing an NSMutableArray between a class and its subclass

Tags: objective-c, inheritance

I have a class `Parent` and a subclass `Child`. `Parent` contains an `NSMutableArray`, and I need to use the same array in the subclass. Any changes to the array in `Parent` should be reflected in `Child`.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Is there any relation between interface `A`, `B` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use pointers?

```
NSMutableArray *a = [NSMutableArray new];
NSMutableArray *b = a;
```

Any change done to b will be done to a too and vice versa.

Comment: NSMutableArray *a = [NSMutableArray new];
NSMutableArray *b = a; How will I get b( which is a class A variable) in class B?

Comment: @JohnValiaveettil: `B.array = A.array`

Answer (score 1):

Since you're talking about sharing a particular array, it's worth pointing out that you must really be talking about a specific instances of A and B. You need to arrange some sort of relationship between A and B -- maybe object A creates object B, or the object that creates both of them gives object A a pointer to object B. Whatever the case, [one of those objects needs a pointer to the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720933/moving-a-nsstring-to-a-uiview-from-a-different-class/7720969#7720969) so that either object A can pass object B a pointer to it's array, or object B can request a pointer to object A's array. Once object B has a pointer to the array, any changes it makes to the array will automatically exist in object A's array because *there's only one array*.

Comment: Does objective C has a concept called static array?